# How to make precise: f(x) is approximately 1, for x close to 1? (Alternatives to Taylor approximation?)

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation

Let
$$f(x) = \frac{3}{2+x^{-1}}$$
**I want to say that $f(x) \approx 1$ for $x$ close to $1$.**

This is clearly true in *some* sense: it's true for $x=1$ exactly. Is there a way of making this statement mathematically precise?

Unfortunately, it's not true as a linear approximation! Doing a first-order Taylor expansion of $f$ around $x=1$ we get:

$
\begin{align*}
f(x) &\approx f(1) + \left(-\frac{3}{x^2} [2+x^{-1}]^{-2} \right)_{|x=1} \cdot (x-1) 
\\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{3} \left(x-1\right)
\\
&\neq 1
\end{align*}
$

So in the Taylor linear approximation sense, the statement is not true.

Is there another way to make the statement precise?

Thank you!

Comment: Sure, it is not equal to $1$; but we want *close* to $1$, and $1-\frac{1}{3}(x-1)$ is indeed close to $1$ for $x$ close to $1$

Comment: Yes exactly! But I'm wondering if there's a way to state "indeed close to 1" mathematically precisely.

Comment: You can say that $f(x)=1+\mathcal{O}(x)$ as $x\to 1$

Comment: But this is.. the same really. What do you mean by "precise"? What would you consider precise?

Comment: Your zeroth-order Taylor approximation makes precise that it is close to 1, up to O(x) for x of order>0 -- that's what I'm hoping for in terms of "precise".

Basically I'm hoping that there might be some alternative to Taylor approximations and big O notation which I had never heard of, which let me say something more than just "zeroth order approximation". Quite possibly that is all I can do though!

Comment: @FShrike It should be $f(x)=1+\mathcal O(x-1)$ as $x\to 1$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have a sign error
$$f(x)=\frac{3}{2+\frac{1}{x}}=1+\frac{1}{3}(x-1)+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$
Now, if your problem is to find the best linear approximation for $a \leq x \leq b$, the problem is different.

You can use the $L^2$ norm
$$\Phi(\alpha,\beta)=\int_{1-a}^{1+a}\Bigg[\frac{3}{2+\frac{1}{x}}-(\alpha+\beta\,x) \Bigg]^2\,dx$$ and minimize it as you do for linear regression. This will give
$$\alpha=\frac{3 \left(4 a^3+6a-\left(2 a^2+9\right) \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 a}{3}\right)\right)}{8 a^3}$$
$$\beta=-\frac{9 \left(2 a-3 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 a}{3}\right)\right)}{8 a^3}$$

while
$$\Psi=\int_{1-a}^{1+a}\Bigg[\frac{3}{2+\frac{1}{x}}-\left(1+\frac{1}{3}(x-1)\right)  \Bigg]^2\,dx=$$ will give something larger. If $a$ is small, we have
$$\frac \Psi \Phi=\frac{9}{4}+\frac{6 a^2}{35}+O\left(a^4\right)$$

Look at the values as a function of $a$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
a & 10^4\,\Psi & 10^4\,\Phi & \frac \Psi \Phi\\
 0.1 & 0.00199 & 0.00089 & 2.252 \\
 0.2 & 0.06568 & 0.02910 & 2.257 \\
 0.3 & 0.52338 & 0.23116 & 2.264 \\
 0.4 & 2.36186 & 1.03897 & 2.273 \\
 0.5 & 7.88488 & 3.45437 & 2.283 \\
 0.6 & 21.9607 & 9.58924 & 2.290 \\
 0.7 & 54.4922 & 23.7606 & 2.293 \\
 0.8 & 125.560 & 54.8523 & 2.289 \\
 0.9 & 276.835 & 121.796 & 2.273 \\
 1.0 & 599.172 & 267.558 & 2.239
\end{array}
\right)$$ Notice that, according to this criteria, the first approach is more than twice "better".

For sure, for $x=1$,
$$\alpha+\beta=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{3 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 a}{3}\right)}{4 a}\neq 1$$ which the prize to pay for the improvement. But notice that, if $a$ is small
$$\alpha+\beta=1-\frac{2 a^2}{27}+O\left(a^4\right)$$